# Odd situation for "cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called"

Tags: java

Why doesn't this code compile?

```
public class A {
    public class B extends A {
        public B(A a) { }
    }
    void foo() {
        A a = new A();
        new B(a) { };
    }
}
```

`A.java:[7,17] cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called`

Compilation is successful if either of these changes are made:

- `B` is private instead of public
- line 7 reads `new B(A);` instead of `new B(A) { }`

Using javac version: 1.6.0_20

Comment: What do you think `new B(a) {}` does?

Comment: new B(a) {} should instantiate an anonymous subclass of B whose default constructor calls super(a)

Comment: Obviously, the actual code I'm trying to write has overriding methods in that block - new B(a) { /* stuff goes here */} - but I removed unnecessary code for the purpose of simplifying this question.

Comment: +1; good hard question and awesome job at minimizing the snippet to illustrate the problem.

Comment: "B is private instead of public" - this does not make the problem go away in my case. Making it `static` obviously does, though.

Comment: polygenelubricants, have you tried compiling it?  It works (for me, at least) if B is private.  If you're getting different behavior, then maybe we're looking at a javac bug.

Comment: It's #90 in Joshua Bloch's Java Puzzlers. Available as #9 in its sample chapter: http://www.javapuzzlers.com/java-puzzlers-sampler.pdf. Personally, I can't understand it even after reading the solution.

Comment: @axtavt: Yes, you're right I think this is related (the anon class is analogous to `Inner2 extends Inner1`); @Christopher: I was able to compile with `javac` making `private class B`, but Eclipse does not compile! Yet another case where `javac` and Eclipse compiler disagrees, it seems.

Comment: I'll also note that Intellij IDEA disagrees with everyone - It thinks all of this code is fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<sub>It should be noted that Eclipse, `javac`, and Intellij IDEA exhibit differences in behaviors with regards to these snippets. `javac` and the *Java Puzzlers* behavior is used for reference in this discussion.</sub>

I was able to cut down the snippet to the following:

```
public class A {
    class B extends A {
    }
    void foo() {
        new B() { }; // DOES NOT COMPILE!!
    }
}
```

This scenario is discussed in [*Java Puzzlers*](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/java-puzzlers-sampler.pdf), *Puzzle 90: It's Absurd, It's a Pain, It's Superclass!*

The snippet given is the following:

```
public class Outer {                   // "A"
    class Inner1 extends Outer  {}     // "B"
    class Inner2 extends Inner1 {}     // "B" anonymous
}
// DOES NOT COMPILE!!
```

The problem is that due to how default constructor is defined, we really have the following:

```
// Same as above but with default constructor included explicitly
public class Outer {
    class Inner1 extends Outer  { 
        Inner1() { super(); }
    }
    class Inner2 extends Inner1 {
        Inner2() { super(); }    
    }
}
// STILL DOES NOT COMPILE!!
```

The problem is that `Inner2`'s superclass is itself an inner class `Inner1`, thus making `Inner2`'s default constructor illegal since it requires an enclosing instance to be supplied to the constructor.

The "brute-force" way to fix the problem is to provide this explicitly with a qualified-`this` expression:

```
// "brute-force" fix
public class Outer {
    class Inner1 extends Outer  { 
        Inner1() { super(); }
    }
    class Inner2 extends Inner1 {
        Inner2() { Outer.this.super(); }    
    }
}
// NOW COMPILES!
```

However, the puzzle prescribes that such complicated situation is best avoided in the first place. Here are some quotes:

> This compiles, but it is mind-numbingly complex. There is a better solution: Whenever you write a member class, ask yourself, Does this class really need an enclosing instance? If the answer is no, make it `static`. Inner classes are sometimes useful, but they can easily introduce complications that make a program difficult to understand. They have complex interactions with generics (Puzzle 89), reflection (Puzzle 80), and inheritance (this puzzle). If you declare `Inner1` to be `static`, the problem goes away. If you also declare `Inner2` to be `static`, you can actually understand what the program does: a nice bonus indeed.
>
> In summary, it is rarely appropriate for one class to be both an inner class and a subclass of another. More generally, it is rarely appropriate to extend an inner class; if you must, think long and hard about the enclosing instance. Also, prefer `static` nested classes to non-`static`. Most member classes can and should be declared `static`.

Comment: The document linked by axtavt simplifies this even further. using only named classes:

public class A {
    class B extends A { }
    class C extends B { }
}

This time, even IDEA notices that something is wrong:
"Cannot reference C.this before supertype constructor has been called"

Comment: Great answer - This makes technical sense, and furthermore, its conclusion is absolutely correct: I ran into trouble, ultimately, because B really should have been static in the first place.  I ended up making the "B" in my real code a top-level class.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the goal is exactly, but try this.  Note I also cut out the passing of A as an argument as being non-static classes they are already linked.   I included the syntax for referring to the outer class "this" for those situations were the inner class may cover up an outer class field/method

```
public class A {

    protected String field = "a";

    public class B extends A {
        protected String field = "b";

        public B() {
            System.out.println("" + A.this.field + " " + this.field);
        }

        @Override
        void foo() {
            System.out.println("b.foo()");
        }
    }

    void foo() {
        A a = new A();
        a.field = "a2";
        B b = a.new B() {
            @Override
            void foo() {
                System.out.println("b.anon.foo()");
            }
        };

        b.foo();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().foo();
    }
}
```

Running this will output:

```
a2 b
b.anon.foo()
```

Hope this helps!