# Why is my call to super() in Java constructor being flagged as error?

Tags: java, constructor, abstract, super

I have:

- an abstract Message class,
- an abstract CustomMessage extending Message,
- a concrete SpecializedCustomMessage class extending CustomMessage,

as shown below, and I'm having trouble with the concrete class's constructor's call to super().  I've left out many details that I assume are irrelevant to the error I'm encountering.  Is there a problem with having two levels of abstraction before deriving a concrete class?

```
public abstract class Message {
    private int priority;
    Message() {
        priority = 1;
    }
}
public abstract class CustomMessage extends Message {
    CustomMessage() {
        super();
    }
}
public class SpecializedCustomMessage extends CustomMessage {
    SpecializedCustomMessage() {
        /*
         * The following is flagged with the error:
         * "cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called"
         */
        super();
    }
}
```

Edit: as requested, the entire file.  Search for LoadCyclerMessage().

```
package ibm1620;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * Class Message: an object containing an event.  See
 * PriorityFIFOEventQueue for implementation of queue.
 *
 * @author Richard Jowsey <richard@jowsey.com>
 * @author Chap Harrison <clh@pobox.com>
 */
//
//
// Extensive rewrite 7-JUL-2011 by CLH to use queuing to avoid
// having the Producer block until the Consumer catches up.
//
//
public abstract class Message implements Comparable<Message> {

    private int priority;

    Message() {
        this.priority = 1;
    }

    Message(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    /**
     * Comparator to determine relative priority. Called by PriorityFIFOEventQueue.
     */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Message other) {
        // TODO - compare this and other for priority
        return 0; // no priorities yet.
    }

    /**
     * process() is overridden to handle message subclasses
     */
    public abstract void process();

    static void say(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /**
     * Subclass ConsoleEventMessage:
     */
    public static class ConsoleEventMessage extends Message {

        private ConsoleObject obj = ConsoleObject.UNDEFINED_OBJ; // widget that was affected
        private ObjectState state = ObjectState.UNDEFINED_STATE; // the widget's new state

        /**
         * Constructor specifying object and new state.
         */
        public ConsoleEventMessage(ConsoleObject theObj, ObjectState theState) {
            super();
            obj = theObj;
            state = theState;
        }

        @Override
        public void process() {
            // handleConsoleEventMessage(this);
            // what do we do now??
        }

        /**
         * Message accessors
         */
        public ConsoleObject getObj() {
            return this.obj;
        }

        public ObjectState getState() {
            return this.state;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "[" + obj + ": " + state + "]";
        }

        public enum ConsoleObject {

            UNDEFINED_OBJ, RESERVED,
            /** Console keys */
            RESET, DISPLAY_MAR, SAVE, INSERT, RELEASE, START, SIE, SCE,
            /** Console toggle switches */
            POWER, SPARE, DISK, PARITY_CHECK, IO_CHECK, OVERFLOW_CHECK, SENSE_SWITCH_1, SENSE_SWITCH_2, SENSE_SWITCH_3, SENSE_SWITCH_4, EMERGENCY,
            /** Console dial */
            MAR_SELECTOR_DIAL,
            /** Card Reader events */
            LOAD, READ, PUNCH
        }

        public enum ObjectState {

            UNDEFINED_STATE, NA,
            /** Toggle switches */
            OFF, ON,
            /** Console keys */
            PRESSED,
            /** MAR selector dial positions */
            IR_1, IR_2, IR_3, OR_1, OR_2, OR_3, OR_4, OR_5, PR_1, PR_2, PR_3, CR_1
        }
    }


    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /**
     * Subclass CyclerMessage:
     */
    public abstract class CyclerMessage extends Message {
        CyclerMessage() {
            super();
        }
    }

    public static class LoadCyclerMessage extends CyclerMessage {

        LoadCyclerMessage() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public void process() {
            try {
                Cycler.processLoadMessage();
            } catch (CheckStop ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Message.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (BugStop ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Message.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Subclass CardReaderMessage:
     */
    public static class CardReaderMessage extends Message {

        byte[] card;
        boolean lastCardIndicator;

        public CardReaderMessage(byte[] card, boolean lc) {
            super();
            this.card = card;
            this.lastCardIndicator = lc;
        }

        @Override
        public void process() {
            Cycler.processCardReadMessage();
        }

        public byte[] getCard() {
            return card;
        }

        public boolean isLastCard() {
            return lastCardIndicator;
        }
    }

    /* -------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /**
     * Subclass CardPunchMessage: this is sent FROM the punch TO the CPU
     * to acknowledge that the buffer has been accepted and the CPU may now
     * resume.
     */
    public static class CardPunchMessage extends Message {

        PunchMessage message;

        public CardPunchMessage(PunchMessage m) {
            super();
            message = m;
        }

        @Override
        public void process() {
        }

        public PunchMessage getPunchMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public enum PunchMessage {

            BUFFER_ACCEPTED
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that super() is the first call made?

Comment: Is there any code before super()? or is that it?

Comment: @Chap: What does your file *actually* look like?

Comment: I think the example may be over-simplified.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383460/odd-situation-for-cannot-reference-this-before-supertype-constructor-has-been-ca

Comment: @Mehrdad Example was incorrect in that, in the actual file, the subclasses were *nested within* the Message class.  My apologies - I appended the full text of the file to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public abstract class CyclerMessage
```

as opposed to other inner classes above is not declared *static* - why?

Did you test what happens if you declare it static? I wouldn't wonder if that will fix "cannot reference" error

```
public static abstract class CyclerMessage
```

Comment: Yes, it does.  Thanks - I still don't know if this is the best/right approach to defining a hierarchy of Message types, but it solves the problem I was having.

Comment: glad to hear that _this_ helped. I'm kinda on crusade against non-static (named) inner classes. :)

Comment: I think that Joshua Bloch (Effective Java) is down on them too.  But I've discovered a problem with using nested static public classes - they seem not to be visible outside of their package!  Despite being "public".

Comment: hm. Well in my experience these were as a rule perfectly visible - except for specific _corner cases_ like passing via some dumb remote protocol (CORBA or IIOP don't recall exactly) or handling with buggy Eclipse IDE checks

Answer (score 3):

There is no error here. I just ran it successfully.

EDIT:
All of your classes are inner classes of Message. That's the problem (I hope this is not intentional).

Comment: Same here, theres something he left out of his question.

Comment: Question edited to append entire file

Comment: Yikes!  Damn - my bad.  My original example didn't reflect that.  But, I thought that "static nested" classes were "largely" equivalent to top-level classes.

Comment: My intention was to create a hierarchy of message types, and keep them all in the same file.  I *think* it's incorrect to put multiple top-level class definitions into the same file (isn't it?), which was why I went for the static-nested approach instead.  Is there a different way I should approach this?

Comment: why do you want them to be in the same file - that's not necessary... You can have more files in a file, but only one of them can be public.

Comment: I wanted to avoid wild proliferation of files.  Since there will be many different message types at the 3rd level of the hierarchy, I thought it would be easier if they all lived in one file.  The scheme seemed to work when there was just an abstract Message class and a bunch of concrete public static nested FooMessage subclasses, but things fell apart when I added an abstract subclass of Message to further subcategorize the final concrete classes.  Time to go back and AGAIN see if I can wrap my head around nested classes.  Java seems complicated to me.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `priority`.

Java classes are instantiated in the following order:

(at classload time)
 0. initializers for static members and static initializer blocks, in order
    of declaration.

(at each new object)

1. create local variables for constructor arguments
2. if constructor begins with invocation of another constructor for the
   class, evaluate the arguments and recurse to previous step.  All steps
   are completed for that constructor, including further recursion of
   constructor calls, before continuing.
3. if the superclass hasn't been constructed by the above, construct the
   the superclass (using the no-arg constructor if not specified).  Like #2,
   go through all of these steps for the superclass, including constructing
   IT'S superclass, before continuing.
4. initializers for instance variables and non-static initializer blocks, in
   order of declaration.
5. rest of the constructor.

Also, [Odd situation for "cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383460/odd-situation-for-cannot-reference-this-before-supertype-constructor-has-been-ca)

Comment: Apologies for misrepresenting the problem -- the subclasses are actually *inner* classes of the top class.  I appended the full file to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 reasons why `super()` would fail, one of them is that your superclass does not have no-arg constructor, which is **NOT** the case, the other one being that `super()` is **NOT** the first line in your constructor, which I think is the case. Another one as suggested by @EdC would be that your super class constructor is not visible to the class.

Comment: There is a third reason, if the constructor is not visible from the sub-class. If the constructors are package protected (as in the example) but the classes are in different packages then this will fail as described.

Comment: @Kowser what would you suggest?

Comment: Apologies for misrepresenting the problem -- the subclasses are actually inner classes of the top class. I appended the full file to the question.