# Strange compilation error with inner classes

Tags: java, compiler-errors, inner-classes

The following code compiles as expected:

```
class A {
    class B {}
    class C extends B {}
}
```

*But,* if we have class `B` extend class `A`, we receive a compilation error:

```
class A {
    class B extends A {}
    class C extends B {}  // <-- Error here
}
```

```
No enclosing instance of type A is available due to some intermediate 
constructor invocation.
```

What is happening here? Why does extending `A` change anything?

**EDIT:** Apparently, this compiles fine in Java 7. I would appreciate an explanation as to why it did not compile in older Java versions and what was changed in Java 7 to allow for it.

---

**SEE ALSO:**

- [Eclipse Bug 373371](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=373371)

Comment: Please forget about the whole piece of nonsense - this is a bug. Javac works fine in this case. I've edited my answer. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=373371

Comment: @ZiyaoWei This also does not work in IntelliJ

Comment: Javac 7 should work, and if not, adding the constructor does help.

Comment: Dupe found - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383460/odd-situation-for-cannot-reference-this-before-supertype-constructor-has-been-c, but the case has changed since, so I am not marking this as a dupe. Still trying to find related information.

Comment: Found the reference from JLS 7, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Since `B` is not static, it needs some instance of `A` to be able to exist, thus the error.</strike>

<strike>If `B` is static, the error goes away.</strike>

Ah, forget about the nonsense. It is a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=373371), and it works on [ideone](http://ideone.com/fKGS5j) in Java7 mode. However, prior to Java 7 it does not work - [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383460/odd-situation-for-cannot-reference-this-before-supertype-constructor-has-been-c), and you need to either

1. Change B to static
2. Add a constructor

   ```
   C() {
       A.this.super();
   }
   ```

And then it will be working.

The reason why this happens before Java 7 might be the following which is from JLS:

> Let C be the class being instantiated, let S be the direct superclass of C, and let i be the instance being created.

The implicit `super` is called on **the immediately enclosing instance of i with respect to S**.

In the [earlier JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.8.7.1), the immediately enclosing instance is defined as

> Let O be the innermost lexically enclosing class of which S is a member, and let n be an integer such that O is the nth lexically enclosing class of C. The immediately enclosing instance of i with respect to S is the nth lexically enclosing instance of this.

However, in [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1):

> Let O be the innermost lexically enclosing class of S, and let n be an integer such that O is the n'th lexically enclosing class of C.
>
> The immediately enclosing instance of i with respect to S is the n'th lexically enclosing instance of this.

So in the past it was the **innermost lexically enclosing class of which S is a member** while now it is **the innermost lexically enclosing class of S**, so it changed from `C` to `A`, thus the code works in Java 7.

Comment: The second is like calling itself again which will cause it to call itself infinitely. Recursively.

Answer (score 0):

It's a recursion.
If B extends A, and A has a new B in itself, so that B will extend A again, and so on...

As mentioned by @ZiyaoWei the error goes away when B is `static`. That's because then the class B will only exist one time.