# JDK 1.7 vs JDK 1.6 inner classes inheritance difference

Tags: java, java-7, inner-classes, java-6

I'm on solving some Java puzzles and stumbled on this one:

```
public class Outer {
    class Inner1 extends Outer {}
    class Inner2 extends Inner1 {}
}
```

While compiling this code with `javac 1.6.0_45` I'm getting, as expected, this error:

```
Outer.java:8: cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called
class Inner2 extends Inner1 {}                                                                                                
^
```

This is because of compiler generates default constructor for `Inner2` class with similar code, which explains error above:

```
Inner2 () {
    this.super();
}
```

And it's obvious now, because you really can't do this in Java 1.6.0_45, JLS 8.8.7.1 (as I can guess):

> An explicit constructor invocation statement in a constructor body may
>   not refer to any instance variables or instance methods declared in
>   this class or any superclass, or use this or super in any expression;
>   otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

See ([accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3383555/1981450) in [Odd situation for "cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383460/odd-situation-for-cannot-reference-this-before-supertype-constructor-has-been-c))

But if I try to compile it with `javac 1.7.0_79` - it is OK!

And here goes the question - **What has been changed in Java 1.7, that this code is now correct?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @EJP did you check the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3383555/365237) of that one, as that one does look relevant

Comment: @EJP, also, `this.super()` is **not** equivalent to `super()`. If you try to do this in non-inner non-nested class you will get a compile-time error, prior to [JLS1.6 8.8.7.1]. `If S is not an inner class, or if the declaration of S occurs in a static context, no immediately enclosing instance of i with respect to S exists. A compiletime error occurs if the superclass constructor invocation is a qualified superclass constructor invocation.` Similar to [JLS1.7 8.8.7.1].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like there was discussion of the same problem as the bug [JDK-6708938: Synthetic super-constructor call should never use 'this' as a qualifier](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6708938) on the Java bug tracker.

Also I think it would be great for you to take a look at other Related issues of previous one, for example [JDK-4903103: Can't compile subclasses of inner classes](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4903103)
.

Notice the Fixed Versions of both bugs.

And as the result see [Maintenance Review of JSR 901 (Java Language Specification) for Java SE 7](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/maintenance/jsr901/JLS-JavaSE7-ChangeLog.html).

From [The Java Language Specification Third Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/classes.html#8.8.7.1)

> Otherwise, `S` is an inner member class (§8.5). It is a compile-time
>   error if `S` is not a member of a lexically enclosing class, or of a
>   superclass or superinterface thereof. Let `O` be the innermost lexically
>   enclosing class of which `S` is a member, and let *n* be an integer such
>   that `O` is the *n* th lexically enclosing class of `C`. The immediately
>   enclosing instance of `i` with respect to `S` is the *n* th lexically
>   enclosing instance of this.

And from Maintenance Review of JSR 901 (Java Language Specification) for Java SE 7 (full version, page 242, blue text) or the same in [The Java Language Specification, Java SE 7 Edition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1) (just before section 8.8.8)

> Otherwise, S is an inner member class (§8.5).
>
> Let O be the innermost lexically enclosing class of S, and let n be an integer such that O is
>   the n'th lexically enclosing class of C.
>
> The immediately enclosing
>   instance of i with respect to S is the n'th lexically enclosing
>   instance of this.

So you can see that the part with compile-time error has gone.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Now I have a clue that something definitely has been changed! But I don't understand what exactly. I didn't find any major differences between `JLS SE 7` and `JLS Third Edition` in whole 8.8 section.

Comment: @ar4ers I have added the differences of these two versions of JSL related to the issue.

Comment: Big thank you for your additional notes! Now I understand the difference. And, may be you also know, where can specific behavior definition(like synthetic constructor creation) be found? As I can guess - it is JVMS, am I getting it right?

Comment: @ar4ers I guess you can find it in both JLS (more compiler specific) and JVMS (more runtime specific). If you want to read them you can find them at [Java Language and Virtual Machine Specifications page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/)

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that is has to do with [invoke dynamic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/multiple-language-support.html#invokedynamic) which was added in java 1.7 to prepare for the lambda's in java 8.

Comment: I'v checked it in the first place. Sadly, it is not. I used `javap -c` on all three  `.class` files, `Outer.class`, `Outer$Inner1.class` and `Outer$Inner2.class`. No evidence of `invokedynamic`, only `invokespecial` and `putfield`. I'm currently on investigation of this problem, but no result yet.